# Laravel Base Exception Class

Tags: laravel, exception

When we write in laravel

```
use Exception;
```

what is the underlying class behind it?
or is it php native Exception class?

Comment: no . its the ErrorException of Laravel

Comment: if  you want to use the native  Php Exception class. remove use  Exception namespace and use  immediately by  adding backslash on it . eg. \Exception

Comment: @KennethSunday where is that Laravel Exception located in laravel, I could'n find it..

Answer (score 2):

It is PHP native exception, every Laravel exception has a namespace started by `Illuminate`